# How to add css class property based on the Components property

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap list where I show a list of Dashboards. By default one of the Dashboard which starts with some name must be selected by default, by adding a css class to existing class attribute something like below.

```
<a *ngFor="let user of userModel" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">{{user.dashBoardName}}</a>
```

the class active of class attribute of  tag must be added only if the dashBoardName is any string other wise it must be like below

```
<a *ngFor="let user of userModel" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{user.dashBoardName}}</a>
```

How can we do that using Angular. By the way I am new to the Angular stuff though.

Comment: You can add a classname depend of the router. Please take a look at [Angular Router and Active Links](https://angular.io/guide/router#active-router-links)

Comment: Take a look at [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `[class.xxx]` directive with your `active` class name, as below :

```html
<a *ngFor="let user of userModel" [class.active]="user.dashBoardName === 'activeDashboard'" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{user.dashBoardName}}</a>
```

This directive will add `active` class name if condition is `true`.

You can also move your logic inside a method of your component, to keep your template simple :

in component.ts :

```js
isActive(user: User) {
  return user.dashBoardName === 'activeDashboard';
}
```

in template.html:

```html
<a *ngFor="let user of userModel" [class.active]="isActive(user)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive

```html
<a *ngFor="let user of userModel" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [ngClass]="user.dashBoardName === 'activeUser' ? 'active' : ''">{{user.dashBoardName}}</a>
```

Here I check against a constant literal `'activeUser'`. You could also replace it with a variable defined in the controller. Then use the variable name without the single quotes.