# Angular - Change the container height based on the route

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a container where I load my grids based on the route. For example,

admin.component.html

```
    <div class="admin-right-panel">              
      <div class="grid-style">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the router-outlet, I will load my grid pages/components based on the route
Here is the CSS for above HTML

admin.component.scss

```
    .admin-right-panel {
        height: 60vh;
    }
```

So, there is an ask for me, where I need to increase this height when I load a specific page into the container.

Let's say I have components A, B, C and when I load B then I need the height to be `80vh`, but keep as `60vh` in the case of A, B.

Each component has it's own `HTML`, `SCSS`, `TS` files. Is there a way I can implement this logic? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally add class using `ngClass` and subscribing to Router events to check what is the path of the URL.

```
import {Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/core';

...
path!: string;

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.router.events.pipe(filter((event) => event instanceOf NavigationEnd).subscribe((data) => { 
       this.path = this.route.snapshot.path;
   })
}
```

Using path, set the component's class.

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'extraHeight': path === '<YourPath>' }"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite: Create a new class in stylesheet with the required view height in your edge case.
Then, you should be able to do any of the following:

1. [You can use ngClass directive to toggle a class name via a typescript variable.](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives)
2. [You can also use [class.largeView]="condition_in_typescript" to add a class largeView to your list of classes. It will only get added when condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815878/how-to-add-css-class-property-based-on-the-components-property).
3. You can wrap two layouts in ngTemplate with a *ngIf and toggle according to path variable in typescript.
4. [You can use HostBinding in a directive to bind multiple classes in your element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639098/using-a-directive-to-add-class-to-host-element).